# angularjs watch an image to see if it has finished loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular How can I watch an image to see if it has finished loading inside a directive?

For example show an alert when the image has been fully retrieved from the URL (not when the div is rendered).

html:

```
 <img src="{{thumbnail}}" image-loading-spinner/>
```

directive:

```
directive('imageLoadingSpinner', ['$document', '$parse', function ($document, $parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             // get item to watch?
             scope.$watch(????, function (newValue) {
               //has loaded image url?
               alert('got the image!')
          )}

        }
    };


}]).
```

Comment: @RGraham I tested that code and it does not run after the image has been retrieved so it fires at the wrong time. http://jsfiddle.net/2CsfZ/2/

Comment: Then you should pose *that* as a question. As it stands, this question is a duplicate and already has an answer.

Comment: Update OP as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would not be an existing watch expression for that. You could code your a custom watch function, but I would advise against that. Watches are evaluated quite often. And what you're looking for is single event.

You should look into reacting to both `load` and `error` events instead.